# java.lang.NullPointerException -> org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException while starting up jetty server

Tags: java, maven, jetty, pom.xml

Following is my project structure :

```
ImgUploadImg -> pom.xml
             -> base      -> pom.xml
             -> auxiliary -> pom.xml
             -> webapp    -> pom.xml
```

Parent Pom file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0                     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>pl.imguploadimg</groupId>
<artifactId>ImgUploadImg</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
     <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
     <version>2.5</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
     <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
     <version>2.1</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
     <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
     <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
     <version>4.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
     <version>1.9.12</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- LogBack dependencies -->
  <dependency>
     <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
     <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
     <version>1.1.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
     <version>1.7.7</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- JUnit Dependencies-->
  <dependency>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
     <version>3.8.1</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
  <plugins>
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
        <configuration>
           <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
           <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
        </configuration>
     </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
<modules>
   <module>base</module>
   <module>auxiliary</module>
   <module>webapp</module>
</modules>
</project>
```

base/pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <groupId>pl.imguploadimg</groupId>
    <artifactId>ImgUploadImg</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>pl.imguploadimg.base</groupId>
<artifactId>base</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Everything Else -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.29</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>xerces</groupId>
     <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
     <version>2.4.0</version>
 </dependency>


</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>base</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
   </build>
  </project>
```

auxiliary/pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0                       http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <groupId>pl.imguploadimg</groupId>
    <artifactId>ImgUploadImg</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>pl.imguploadimg.auxiliary</groupId>
<artifactId>auxiliary</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pl.imguploadimg.base</groupId>
        <artifactId>base</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>auxillary</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

and finally, webapp/pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0                       http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <groupId>pl.imguploadimg</groupId>
    <artifactId>ImgUploadImg</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>pl.imguploadimg.webapp</groupId>
<artifactId>webapp</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pl.imguploadimg.auxiliary</groupId>
        <artifactId>auxiliary</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pl.imguploadimg.base</groupId>
        <artifactId>base</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Apache Tiles -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Json Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.flexjson</groupId>
        <artifactId>flexjson</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>webapp</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.5.v20130815</version>
            <configuration>
                <webAppConfig>
                    <contextPath />
                </webAppConfig>
                <jettyXml>src/main/resources/jetty-config.xml</jettyXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <filters>
        <filter>src/main/filters/db-config/database-info.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.*</include>
            </includes>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>spring-config/**/*.*</include>
            </includes>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
</project>
```

Code compiles successfully but while starting jetty I get the following error :

```
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------  ---------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.021s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Nov 11 17:30:44 IST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/161M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.BuilderCommon.handleBuildError(BuilderCommon.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:95)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at    org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.ComponentValueSetter.configure(ComponentValueSetter.java:348)
at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.composite.ObjectWithFieldsConverter.processConfiguration(ObjectWithFieldsConverter.java:161)
at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.composite.ObjectWithFieldsConverter.fromConfiguration(ObjectWithFieldsConverter.java:89)
at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.ComponentValueSetter.configure(ComponentValueSetter.java:348)
at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.composite.ObjectWithFieldsConverter.processConfiguration(ObjectWithFieldsConverter.java:161)
at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.BasicComponentConfigurator.configureComponent(BasicComponentConfigurator.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.populatePluginFields(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:567)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:529)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:92)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
... 16 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/InternalErrorException
```

Kindly help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note: Jetty 9.0.x is a transitional release for the Servlet 3.1 spec (it uses draft/beta versions of the Servlet 3.1 api).  Consider at least upgrading to Jetty 9.2.x (or Jetty 9.3.x if you are on Java 8 already)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your `contextpath` variable is undefined:**

```
<contextPath />
```

you need to change it to something meaningful, like:

```
<contextPath>/</contextPath>
```

This will map your webapp to the root context, so you can access it by:

```
http://host:port/
```